# How to select all the occurrences in QTextBrowser

Tags: python, pyqt, qtextbrowser

The code creates `QTextBrowser` window filled with the lines of text.
I would like to select all the words matching "Long Line"
How to achieve it?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

view = QtGui.QTextBrowser() 
for i in range(25):
    view.append(10*('Long Line of text # %004d '%i) )
view.setLineWrapMode(0)

view.find('Long Line')

view.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`QTextEdit.setExtraSelections`:](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#setExtraSelections)

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QApplication, QTextEdit, QTextBrowser, QTextCursor,
                         QTextCharFormat, QPalette)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
view = QTextBrowser()
for i in range(25):
    view.append(10*('Long Line of text # %004d '%i) )
view.setLineWrapMode(0)
line_to_find = 'Long Line'

# get default selection format from view's palette
palette = view.palette()
text_format = QTextCharFormat()
text_format.setBackground(palette.brush(QPalette.Normal, QPalette.Highlight))
text_format.setForeground(palette.brush(QPalette.Normal, QPalette.HighlightedText))

# find all occurrences of the text
doc = view.document()
cur = QTextCursor()
selections = []
while 1:
    cur = doc.find(line_to_find, cur)
    if cur.isNull():
        break
    sel = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()
    sel.cursor = cur
    sel.format = text_format
    selections.append(sel)
view.setExtraSelections(selections)

view.show()
app.exec_()
```

And here is the result:

[image: the QTextBrowser on win7]

Alternatively try [`QSyntaxHighlighter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsyntaxhighlighter.html).